# Search with multiple range values on same item

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, algolia

I'm implementing a search filter via [instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#rangeslider) with a range slider.

The slider filters a range of years based on the `year` data column of each item. In this DB tho there are some items with no precise year, but a "supposed" period, like "circa XVIII sec" or "End of 1910s". This means that for these items there is not a single year to filter but rather multiple years.

Let's say for ex. that I wish to filter results in a range of years from 1874 to 1930 and I have an item with "Second half 19th century" in the `year` field. As you can tell it should result in the match, since any year from 1851 to 1900 is correct for this item.

How should I treat this type of data to be part of this filter range?
How should I structure the data in the `year` column of this DB?

Should I use some script logic in the algolia javascript search rather than use a special way of structuring the data or indexing?

I was thinking of a logic like:

> "If value of item is not just digits, convert it to a range of years.
> Then check if the range of these years can match with the filter required in
> the slider"

I can't really tell how to do this, and it looks a bit cumbersome and silly to me. I'm pretty sure this is no new issue to face in DB data design, so there has to be a proper way to address it.

I tried searching around but I don't even know how to proper word this thing I'm asking..  if you have suggestions to edit the title please do tell me!

I'm using a MySQL database along with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Algolia, you'll need to convert this values to timestamp then you would be able to use numericFilter and add a range slider or numeric refinement list component to your UI.

Also the attribute must be defined as an attributesForFaceting in your index configuration.

https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#rangeslider

https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#numericrefinementlist

Comment: Thank you! Are you telling me that I'm able, providing say 2 columns, to search for those columns values and filter them within the range of provided values in the slider just out of the box?

Comment: I dig a bit in your use case and unfortunately the range slider we are providing right now doesn't allow you to use 2 columns on the same slider. But good news, the widget should be updated to allow that with a modification. Our team will look at it: 
https://github.com/instantsearch/instantsearch-ion.rangeSlider/issues/4
It's a use case that makes sens, thanks for reporting it.
In the meantime you can still use 2 sliders (start and end date) or  numeric refinement list.

Comment: edit: our team just made the modification, please tell us if it works for you!
https://github.com/instantsearch/instantsearch-ion.rangeSlider/commits/master

Comment: Nice thanks a lot! :) Actually I kinda got it working using the `numericFilters` with an [array as suggested in the docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/php#one-to-many-association). Using a filter like `"numericFilters": [ "years>=1895", "years<=1905" ]` gives me back the results as expected, now I was just trying to implement it with the slider. I'll try also with your commit and let you know!

Comment: Re Gruber, any chance you had time to try the commit? Let us know.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I haven't got back in these days, I had (and unfortunately still have) other things to do and this particular project got a bit delayed. I'll  let you know indeed as soon as I can get back on this, hopefully this week! Thank you for caring for this ;)

Comment: Sorry it took way more than planned :P Thank you again for this update, it's working nice indeed! Just a little suggestion for _slow_ people like me: took me a bit to get it working because the data passed was stored (dunno why) as `string` type rather than `integer` so the widget wasn't working; a little heads up in the docs remembering people to pass data as integer can help I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `year` as a range, you can either add a `beggining` and an `end` attribute to those fields. Example:

> EventTimes

```
id SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY,
yearEnd DATETIME,
yearStart DATETIME
```

In this case, the end and the start will be equal (I use null ends), when the event is an specific time, and becomes a range when the two fields are filled.

When `SELECT`ing, you can always check for both fields, without a significant loss of speed or accuracy. Then check either for specific time, range of times, or if an event begins, ends, re-begins, re-ends and so on, you can check for different fields within the same table.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is indeed interesting and probably the best way to address the possible vague value and how to store it in the DB. I don't get what that 'EventTimes' is though, is it the name of the table where to store the time range? You suggest a 1-1 relationship with the items table?

Comment: EventTimes is the name of the table. While as far as I have needed there were 1 "time" for each event, you can make ID not primary, and have that value be an identifier for the collumn in your other table, so you can have 1-N "times" for each event.

Comment: Interesting thank you! The 1-M table is a useful addition but in my case not really needed, still you have pointed me in the right direction on how to handle the data in the DB, unfortunately I can only +1 once :)

Comment: If you solved your problem, or have found a direction to study, then either "close" the question, or accept something as the answer, this way, newer people can check your problem, and read some helpful answer.... also, this signals other forum users that you wont be checking the question anymore.